# Gradle has installed external libraries but they're not resolving

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, dependency-management, kotlin-js

I am new to the Kotlin language and the Gradle build system, and while I enjoy the language, I have spent more time over the last 4 days trying to *build* my projects rather than write them.
I have tagged this with Gradle even though some might say its not Gradle related, because I literally have no experience with Gradle so I don't know if I'm doing anything right at all. I created my Gradle project with IntelliJ, targeting Kotlin/JS for browser.

Gradle installs external dependencies just fine (supposedly), but Intellij won't resolve them. Do I have to do something special with my build script to resolve these? On the IntelliJ end, I've invalidated caches, I've reimported the project, etc etc. I am also knew the IntelliJ, but I can't comprehend what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Snapshot of my IDE, showing installed libraries but unresolved references]

Here is my build.gradle script:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js' version '1.3.72'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    //mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js"
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:5.0.1'
}

kotlin.target.browser { }
```

Comment: AFAIU, this library doesn't have js target, so you can't use it with KotlinJS. You can use https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization

Comment: Alas, I believe you are correct. Last night I tried installing serialization to see if it was indeed a target issue, although serialization didn't resolve correctly so I assumed it was not. Your comment persuaded me to try installing again a little differently and it works now.